# No error logs created in var/report

Tags: error, reports, debug

I recently bought a magento site from someone. I am now trying to move it to my own host, but the only thing I get is an error message. Trying to debug it, I googled around and I've seen the error report should b in var/report, but none is created there.

What I have already done

1. Set rights on var and var/report to 777
2. Changed development mode in index.php and .htaccess
3. Renamed local.xml.sample to local.xml in errors folder
4. Renamed the template folder so these are not loaded
5. Set all modules to inactive by editing the xmls in app/etc/modules
6. Deleted the cache folders several times

What more can I do to get my error reports, so I can start debugging?

Thanks for any answer, IJsbrand

Still I get no error reports in var/report and none on the screen either

Comment: Have you checked in the backend? `System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings`

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Thanks guys, totally forgot to check the backend after chaning all this stuff. The backend gave some readable error messages, turned out to be an unsupported php version. (Old Magento version, need to upgrade soon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem turned out to be an unsupported PHP version. Changed the PHP version on the host and the site works like a charm.

Comment: Which PHP Version did you used?